# Foreign Keys SQL relational to user table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn about Foreign keys and being able to associated data from one table to another. So I have a users table and a cards table.

The user table has 'user_id', 'username' & 'email'.
The card table has 'card_id' & 'name'.

what I am looking to do is associate a card form the card table to the users. so for example if the card table has Card1 inside and user1 wants that card (or more) assocaited with them how would I use the foreign key to do this.

Here is how I am selecting and showing my users at the moment:

```
    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, email_address FROM user";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  
                $row["username"] . "<br>",
                $row["email_address"] . "<br><br>";
            }

        } else {
            echo "0 Members";
        }

        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

I understand inside of the user table I will need to another another cell 'card_id' but not sure on which data type this should be?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, since the value of card_id is number (I believe), its type should be INT

Comment: Well, I am also trying to wrap my head around how I can associate the user with the card id?

Comment: It's hard to understand your situation. Can you please provide an example in your question? What's the "cards" table standing for? What are the restrictions - can a user have more than one card, can one card belong to more than one user?

Comment: so the cards table is reffering to playing cards. A user can collect the cards so they become a part of the users deck essentially. I want a way for the card to be associated to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and on your following comment:

> so the cards table is reffering to playing cards. A user can collect
>   the cards so they become a part of the users deck essentially. I want
>   a way for the card to be associated to the user.

I believe you can achieve that in 2 ways, depends on further scenarios in your game/script.

**Scenario 1:**
In case one card can be belong to only one user.
Add a new field to the `cards table`.

```
`user_id` INT(11)
```

When a user collect a card, just update that field so it will store the user's id.

**Scenario 2:**
In case one card can be belong to many users.
Create a new table called `users_cards`:

```
users_card
- id (INT)
- user_id (INT)
- cart_id (INT)
```

When a user collect a card, insert a new record to that table with both the card's id and the user's id.

[image: Scenario2]

Comment: For reference, this is a Many to Many join table/intermediary table.